# file_get_contents giving failed to open stream: Connection timed out error for file on same server

Tags: php, timeout, file-get-contents

I am trying to have a file on my server send post data as if coming from a form ("calling_file.php") to another file on the same server ("processing_file.php"). Here is the code:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/processing_file.php';
$method = 'POST';

$eol = "\r\n";

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 30,
        'method' => $method,
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . $eol,
        'content' => http_build_query($xmit)
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); //filename, use_include_path, context

//echo($result);
$result_decode = json_decode($result,true);
```

$xmit looks something like this:

```
array(
    'dx' => json_encode('[{"business_date":"2015-09-29","check_avg":10.749122993789,"guests":"422"},{"business_date":"2015-09-30","check_avg":36.735215894737,"guests":"461"},{"business_date":"2015-10-01","check_avg":12.2527145,"guests":"288"},{"business_date":"2015-10-02","check_avg":18.405998957055,"guests":"263"},{"business_date":"2015-10-03","check_avg":20.385927936508,"guests":"289"}]'),
    'period' => 5,
    'phase_code' => 3,
    'site_id' => 155
)
```

When I echo out $opts, everything looks right. http_build_query($xmit) is creating what looks to be valid post data. I have this set in processing_file.php and calling_file.php:

```
ini_set('allow_url_include', '1');
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
```

When I paste: 
    http://www.example.com/path/to/processing_file.php

directly in my browser, the file opens with 200 status, all good.

I tried setting the owner of processing_file to be the apache user, and set chmod to 775 on it.

However, when calling_file.php tries to call processing_file.php with the above code, I get this:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/path/to/processing_file.php): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/example.com/functions/path/to/other/file/calling_file.php on line 219
```

line 219 is:

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); //filename, use_include_path, context
```

I can't figure out why it can't see the file.

Comment: If you can get to a command line:  Can it resolve www.example.com?  Can you use wget or curl?  Does it work using http?  Does it work without the context (plain GET)?

Comment: curl did not work (error: curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl) and wget also timed out: (--2016-12-13 07:23:48--  https://www.example.com/path/to/processing_file.php
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... xx.xxx.xxx.xx
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|xx.xxx.xxx.xx|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue over the weekend and found that it was affecting me on ArchLinux and a fresh install of Fedora 25.

For a little more context, I found doing *any* network calls over `file_get_contents()` was timing out, *while doing the equivalent network call with cURL was succeeding*. Additionally, `ping` was suffering the same issues.

Some low level, system-wide, utility that `file_get_contents()` was using internally was resolving DNS by doing IPv6 lookups and subsequently timing out. Strangely enough, all my other applications, (cURL, web browser, etc.) were using IPv4 and working properly.

**I resolved this by disabling IPv6 system wide.**

---

For documentation's sake, these were my `ping`s that demonstrate the issue:

Ping, using the default invocation:

```
[hpierce@localhost ~]$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com(ord38s04-in-x04.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:813::2004)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
147 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 149492ms
```

Ping, using the flag for IPv4:

```
[hpierce@localhost ~]$ ping www.google.com -4
PING www.google.com (172.217.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord38s04-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.0.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from ord38s04-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.0.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=16.9 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.958/17.939/18.921/0.990 ms
```

Comment: Please see my comment above. I tried curl and wget and both also failed. Unfortunately, I can't disable ipv6 on this computer. Also, we are using Debian 7.9.